# Broadcasting a graph in Pregel Api in Graphx?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

What I would like to do is to broadcast the graph I created to all of the vertices and then each vertex can do its own computation on this graph to compute shortest path with respect to itself as the source vertex? The code below always when I try accessing the graph in the method compute gives me:
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
val result=graph.pregel(graph,Int.MaxValue,EdgeDirection.Out)((id, value, msg) => compute(msg,id),triplet => Iterator.empty,(a, b) => a)
```

Comment: can you show a reproducible example including data and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have iterative limitations, or want to compute the shortest path to a (temporally) changing node, it might be far easier to compute this with the help of `org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.ShortestPaths` [[1]](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.ShortestPaths$), and calling this on each of your vertices.

Either way, the memory consumption for this will blow out of proportion for only medium-sized graph. Unless you have a really large cluster, or only a small graph, this will most likely be an insurmountable task.

Providing further information on your setting could maybe improve the answers given.

Comment: What I would like to do exactly is if we suppose algorithms such as betweenness centrality or all pair shortest paths or any algorithm that requires a computation on each vertex of the graph , then we must definitely have ( for each vertex v do some computation) . I want to do this for loop in parallel on only one graph

Comment: But then you would inherently loose the optimization of spark, since its efficiency lies within the parallel distribution of tasks. If you want to perform this on only one graph (which is btw not possible, since shortestPaths does return another graph with the path lengths as vertex attributes anyways). The problem is that you do seem to forget that both centrality and pageRank have iterative solutions, and no different graphs for each node

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer to this question if someone out there is trying to do the same thing.

First, as GraphX uses RDDs to store the graph vertices and edges it won't be possible to broadcast a graph this way because we cannot access an RDD inside another RDD. 
This is why you are getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Second, broadcasting the graph like that is a bad idea, you should probably think of *distributed* way to compute the shortest paths for each vertex. For example, instead of having one source vertex, you can trigger the shortest path computation from every single vertex and label your messages with both `length` and `source` to distinguish between different paths.